# How to make kinetic.js image respect html 5 canvas clip restraints

Tags: html, draggable, kineticjs

So, I'm trying to make the below image respect the HTML5 canvas clipping boundaries I've set but it only respects DIV boundaries, the circle on the other hand respects full boundaries

so how do I use html5 clipping with a kinetic.js created image

Link to demo: http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/test3/canvaskinclip.html

--> main problem: the blue ball respects the HTML5 clipping border, but the draggable Darthvader image doesn't (I want to make draggable darthvader respect it)

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.8.3.js">
</script>
 <body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 425, 405);
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
           var background_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var draggingShape = undefined;
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';


        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,

      width: 200,
      height: 137,
      draggable: true


    });
        // circle
        var circle = new Kinetic.Shape({



            drawFunc: function(){
                var context = this.getContext();

                // draw clipping rectangle
               context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(5, 5);
  context.lineTo(34, 202);

  context.lineTo(2, 405);
  context.lineTo(212, 385);
  context.lineTo(425, 405);
  context.lineTo(400, 202);
  context.lineTo(415, 10);
  context.lineTo(212, 25);
                context.clip();

                // draw circle


                imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
                 context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0);
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(this._x, this._y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = "blue";
                context.fill();
                context.closePath();
            },
            // custom properties
            _x: 300,
            _y: 50
        });

        circle.on("mousedown", function(){
            draggingShape = this;
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            draggingRectOffsetX = mousePos.x - circle._x;
            draggingRectOffsetY = mousePos.y - circle._y;
        });
        circle.on("mouseover", function(){
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        });
        circle.on("mouseout", function(){
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });

        layer.add(circle);

        stage.on("mouseout", function(){
            draggingShape = undefined;
        }, false);

        stage.on("mousemove", function(){
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            if (draggingShape) {
                draggingShape._x = mousePos.x - draggingRectOffsetX;
                draggingShape._y = mousePos.y - draggingRectOffsetY;

                layer.draw();
            }
        }, false);

        stage.on("mouseup", function(){
            draggingShape = undefined;
        });




           var Bg = new Image();
    Bg.onload = function() {
            var Bg_image = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: Bg
        });
        background_layer.add(Bg_image);
        stage.add(background_layer);
    layer.add(darthVaderImg);

        stage.add(layer);
    };
    Bg.src = "centerpillow1.png";
    }


</script>
```

Comment: If you can, put this in a jsfiddle so people can play with it, you'll get faster/more accurate responses. Also, switch over to the newest version of kineticjs (or at least a newer one) as that itself might help you with clipping

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fCcUj/

Comment: also, avoid using drawFunc and context.lineTo if you can, try the built in clipping functions that kineticjs now has

Comment: @EliteOctagon so I'm drawing the clipping function using following code -- how can I do the same thing in kinetic.js: '                                                                   `drawFunc: function(){
                var context = this.getContext();

                // draw clipping rectangle
               context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(5, 5);
  context.lineTo(34, 202);

  context.lineTo(2, 405);
  context.lineTo(212, 385);
  context.lineTo(425, 405);
  context.lineTo(400, 202);
  context.lineTo(415, 10);
  context.lineTo(212, 25);
                context.clip(); inline`

Comment: @EliteOctagon http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/test3/canvaskinclip.html

Comment: I take you used this for a guide: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-clipping-regions/

Comment: @EliteOctagon yes, along with a few others -> but when I try to use a  `var myImage = new Kinetic.image({
                drawFunc: function(){ etc etc ...` and try to add my custom clipping region within this it starts shooting out some errors etc

Comment: Yeah, I'm messing with the code in a jsfiddle, I'll update you when I find something

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqaP7/4/  this duplicates the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jzrGP/  I just drew the image in HTML5

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/2/ is one possibility, and jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/7 is an odd implementation which isn't finished, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371383/complex-clipping-boundary-in-kinetic-js-with-draggable-image